# Optional Tables in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, option-type

I have a following relationship between several of my tables:

```
TableA -- 1-to-1 -- TableB -- 1-to-1 -- TableC
                      |___ -- 1-to-1 -- TableD
                      |___ -- 1-to-1 -- TableE
```

The relation between  `TableA` and `TableB` is mandatory, however relation between `TableB` and `TableC`, `TableD`, and `TableE` are *optional*. I need to pull information from all three latter tables, *if available in any*; would that mean that the only option I have is to invoke `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on all the joins? i.e.

```
SELECT a.a1
       , c.c1
       , c.c2
       , d.d1
       , e.e1
       , e.e2
       , e.e3
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b 
   ON a.A_ID = b.AF_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC c 
   ON b.B_ID = c.FB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableD d 
   ON b.B_ID = d.FB_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableE e 
   ON b.B_ID = e.FB_ID
```

Wouldn't this cause the last three joins not to use indexes (Oracle 11.2)? Is there another way to write the query?

Comment: If you need to `SELECT` data from all these tables, then you need the `outer joins`.

Comment: Why would this prevent Oracle from using indexes?  Oracle is quite capable of using indexes for both inner and outer joins.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Are you saying that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will utilize indexes even though it does not need to, since it sees that all the data in the left table needs to be scanned?

Comment: @Malvon . . . I was reacting to the statement that this would cause the query not to use indexes, which seemed to be because of the `left outer join`.  In this particular case, it might or might not use indexes.  For instance, Oracle might still use a covering index for the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Under what condition would Oracle use a covering index then? Is there a way to find out whether tables' relation is bidirectional from a mere DB schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to "force" Oracle you use joins, you could phrase the query as:

```
SELECT a.a1,
       (select c.c1 from TableC c where b.B_ID = c.FB_ID) as c1,
       (select c.c2 from TableC c where b.B_ID = c.FB_ID) as c2,
       (select d.d1 from TableD d where b.B_ID = d.FB_ID) as d1,
       (select e.e1 from TableE e where b.B_ID = e.FB_ID) as e1,
       (select e.e2 from TableE e where b.B_ID = e.FB_ID) as e2,
       (select e.e3 from TableE e where b.B_ID = e.FB_ID) as e3
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableB b 
     ON a.A_ID = b.AF_ID;
```

This formulation might make it more clear how the indexes get used.  (And, this assumes that there is at least one match in each of the optional tables.)